# ¿Como hacer una subconsulta en laravel para obtener array en un json?

Tags: laravel, json, sql

saludos soy nuevo en laravel tengo un problema cada vez que realizo una consulta a mi tabla tengo una tabla de estudiantes que esta relacionada a una tabla de notas, cada vez que realizo una consulta me genera un registro por cada nota del estudiante, lo que busco que en vez de que me cree un registro por cada nota solo me devuelva un array que contenga todas las notas

```
$estudiantes=Estudiante::join('notas','notas.estudiante_id','=','estudiantes.id')
        ->join('salones','salones.id','=','estudiantes.salon_id')
        ->select('estudiantes.id','estudiantes.nombres','estudiantes.dni','salones.seccion','salones.grado','notas.calificacion')
        ->orderBy('estudiantes.id','asc')->paginate(35);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe alguna forma de obtener un array dentro de un json a travez de las consultas por Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que todas las calificaciones del estudiante te salgan en un mismo renglón; puedes auxiliarte del método `GROUP_CONCAT` que agrupa valores aunque estos sean distintos y del método `selectRaw()` en Laravel de este modo.

Solo le añadí un alias a la concatenación que hace `GROUP_CONCAT` para poder recuperar dicho valor de manera mas fácil después.

Como estoy agrupando las notas entonces después debo agrupar los renglones resultantes; por eso dentro del método `groupBy()` pase de nuevo todas las columnas seleccionadas, menos la generada por `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
$estudiantes=Estudiante::join('notas','notas.estudiante_id','=','estudiantes.id')
        ->join('salones','salones.id','=','estudiantes.salon_id')
        ->select('estudiantes.id','estudiantes.nombres','estudiantes.dni','salones.seccion','salones.grado')
        ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(notas.calificacion) AS Calificacion')
        ->groupBy('estudiantes.id','estudiantes.nombres','estudiantes.dni','salones.seccion','salones.grado')
        ->orderBy('estudiantes.id','asc')->paginate(35);
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [método `selectRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Vemos que estás de vuelta Alfredo Paz.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!, me sirvió bastante!!!